# Problems with Tic Tac Toe minimax algorithm

Tags: c++

[image]I have problems with the AI in my tic tac toe program. AI is red, I am blue. I am trying to use the minimax algorithm, so that the AI will always choose the optimal move. However, I have a problem where the AI never wins! Even though I try to play as badly as possible, the worst I can do, is tie. I have tried to make this game probably 3 times, and the minimax function (along with computerTurn function) is mostly copied from the internet, with some tweaks.

If initialize char board[3][3] with some values where the AI will win if it chooses board[2][2], then computerTurn() will actually find that move, so it seems to work when I test it that way. I have no idea why it chooses so badly otherwise when playing.

Here's the code:

**Tic_Tac_Toe.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "ui_Tic_Tac_Toe.h"

#include <algorithm>

class Tic_Tac_Toe : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tic_Tac_Toe(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~Tic_Tac_Toe();

private:
    bool isMovesLeft();
    int evaluate();
    int miniMax(int depth, bool isMax);
    bool isGameEnd();
    void computerTurn();

    struct Move
    {
        int row, col;
    };

    Ui::Tic_Tac_ToeClass ui;
    QMessageBox* messageBox;

    char board[3][3];
    char player = 'o';
    char computer = 'x';


private slots:
    void onCellClicked(int row, int col);
    void onButtonResetClicked();
};
```

**Tic_Tac_Toe.cpp**

```
#include "Tic_Tac_Toe.h"

Tic_Tac_Toe::Tic_Tac_Toe(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    messageBox = new QMessageBox;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '_';
            ui.tbl_grid->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem);
            ui.tbl_grid->item(i, j)->setBackground(Qt::white);
        }
    }
    
    // Computer (X) shall move first, then wait for user to select a cell
    computerTurn();

    connect(ui.tbl_grid, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, &Tic_Tac_Toe::onCellClicked);
    connect(ui.btn_reset, &QPushButton::released, this, &Tic_Tac_Toe::onButtonResetClicked);
}

Tic_Tac_Toe::~Tic_Tac_Toe()
{
    delete messageBox;
}

bool Tic_Tac_Toe::isMovesLeft()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (board[i][j] == '_')
                return true;
    return false;
}

int Tic_Tac_Toe::evaluate()
{
    // Checking for Rows for X or O victory.
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        if (board[row][0] == board[row][1] &&
            board[row][1] == board[row][2])
        {
            if (board[row][0] == player)
                return +10;
            else if (board[row][0] == computer)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    // Checking for Columns for X or O victory.
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        if (board[0][col] == board[1][col] &&
            board[1][col] == board[2][col])
        {
            if (board[0][col] == player)
                return +10;

            else if (board[0][col] == computer)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    // Checking for Diagonals for X or O victory.
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
    {
        if (board[0][0] == player)
            return +10;
        else if (board[0][0] == computer)
            return -10;
    }

    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
    {
        if (board[0][2] == player)
            return +10;
        else if (board[0][2] == computer)
            return -10;
    }

    // Else if none of them have won then return 0
    return 0;
}

int Tic_Tac_Toe::miniMax(int depth, bool isMax)
{
    int score = evaluate();

    // If Maximizer has won the game return his/her
    // evaluated score
    if (score == 10)
        return score;

    // If Minimizer has won the game return his/her
    // evaluated score
    if (score == -10)
        return score;

    // If there are no more moves and no winner then
    // it is a tie
    if (!isMovesLeft())
        return 0;

    // If this maximizer's move
    if (isMax)
    {
        int best = -1000;

        // Traverse all cells
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty
                if (board[i][j] == '_')
                {
                    // Make the move
                    board[i][j] = computer;

                    // Call minimax recursively and choose
                    // the maximum value
                    best = std::max(best,
                        miniMax(depth + 1, !isMax));

                    // Undo the move
                    board[i][j] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    // If this minimizer's move
    else
    {
        int best = 1000;

        // Traverse all cells
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty
                if (board[i][j] == '_')
                {
                    // Make the move
                    board[i][j] = player;

                    // Call minimax recursively and choose
                    // the minimum value
                    best = std::min(best,
                        miniMax(depth + 1, !isMax));

                    // Undo the move
                    board[i][j] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}

void Tic_Tac_Toe::computerTurn()
{
    // Computer will now make its turn
    int bestVal = -1000;
    Move bestMove;
    bestMove.row = -1;
    bestMove.col = -1;

    // Traverse all cells, evaluate minimax function for
    // all empty cells. And return the cell with optimal
    // value.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            // Check if cell is empty
            if (board[i][j] == '_')
            {
                // Make the move
                board[i][j] = computer;

                // compute evaluation function for this
                // move.
                int moveVal = miniMax(0, false);

                // Undo the move
                board[i][j] = '_';

                // If the value of the current move is
                // more than the best value, then update
                // best/
                if (moveVal > bestVal)
                {
                    bestMove.row = i;
                    bestMove.col = j;
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    board[bestMove.row][bestMove.col] = computer;
    ui.tbl_grid->item(bestMove.row, bestMove.col)->setBackground(Qt::red);
}

bool Tic_Tac_Toe::isGameEnd()
{
    int score = evaluate();
    if (score == 10)
    {
        messageBox->setText("You won!");
        messageBox->show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (score == -10)
    {
        messageBox->setText("The computer won...");
        messageBox->show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (!isMovesLeft())
    {
        messageBox->setText("Draw...");
        messageBox->show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Tic_Tac_Toe::onCellClicked(int row, int col)
{
    if (isGameEnd())
        return;

    // User picked a cell
    if (board[row][col] != '_')
    {
        messageBox->setText("This cell is already taken!");
        messageBox->show();
        return;
    }
        
    board[row][col] = player;
    ui.tbl_grid->item(row, col)->setBackground(Qt::blue);

    if (isGameEnd())
        return;

    computerTurn();


    if (isGameEnd())
        return;

}

void Tic_Tac_Toe::onButtonResetClicked()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '_';
            ui.tbl_grid->item(i, j)->setBackground(Qt::white);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Tic_Tac_Toe.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Tic_Tac_Toe w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is way too broad. I suggest that you isolate a single situation where the AI does something else than expected and focus on it.

Comment: Haven't actually read through all your code, but from your description it sounds like that perhaps you have mixed up your min and max? In particular, shouldn't you be calling `int moveVal = miniMax(0, false);` with `true` instead since the computer should take the role of max?

Comment: @beko It should start with false, because the computer will mark a cell first in computerTurn() before it calls minimax, therefore it will be the minimizer's turn next

Comment: @dedObed I added a picture showing one situation where the AI is dumb. AI is red by the way.

Comment: You need to debug this. Print some output step by step and see if the algorithm does what you expect. Test each component seperately. That's how development works.

Comment: @JHBonarius I was attempting it, I usually do this of course, but it doesn't help when there are many recursive calls you know. Maybe if I start with an almost finished game, I can test this. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Another thing that seems suspicious to me is that `evaluate` returns a negative number for the max player (ie. the computer). Otherwise, yeah, you have to step through the debugger and check whether at any point the values seem to be wrong. And perhaps rigorously check against the algorithm's pseudo-code, because as you've said, it's cumbersome to debug this.

Comment: download stuff from github where comp wins then diff it with yours

Comment: @Beko woooow I actually tested changing the negative score for the computer to a positive one, now it works hahah. I still need to go through the code to understand why, but at least it works now!! Thanks a bunch dude

EDIT: How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: You should post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I believe this is reproducible, but the fact that example you posted is far from minimal discourages many people too read this.

Comment: @vetled I'm glad it worked. You can't mark a comment as an answer. I guess the best way to understand how it works is to draw the tree for a substate and step through it. Perhaps someone feels like doing so and can post the answer here.